# Comparing a jbytearray with a string in JNI

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a JNI C function that has an jbyteArray input parameter. This is a byte array of size 128 that I wish to compare with a #define string. How do I achieve this?

I tried to memcpy the jbyteArray to an unsigned char data[128] and then do a memcmp() of data and the #define, but the memcpy crashed my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up copying the jbytearray using GetByteArrayRegion instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetByteArrayElements() to get the byte array contents and then compare using strncmp or memcmp or whatever:

```
#define COMPARE_STRING "somestring" // can be up to 128 bytes long

// JNIEnv *pEnv
// jbyteArray byteArray

// get the byte array contents:
jbyte* pBuf = (jbyte*)(*pEnv)->GetByteArrayElements(pEnv, byteArray, 0);
if(pBuf)
{
    // compare up to a maximum of 128 bytes:
    int result = strncmp((char*)pBuf, COMPARE_STRING, 128);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up copying the jbytearray using GetByteArrayRegion instead. That worked.